# Size of my buttons does not change

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here is my code for changing buttons size of buttons:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    int Orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if(Orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(10,100));
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50,50));
        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(height/9,width/6));
        Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btn4.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(height/9,width/6));
        Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btn5.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(height/9,width/6));
        Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        btn6.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(height/9,width/6));
```

Now matter what values i put in the width and height part size of all buttons, remain same.How can i change their size.

Comment: Have you tried calling requestLayout on the parent after setting all the parameters to force it to recalculate?

Comment: NO i have not done it. Where should i do it.

Comment: After you resize all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach,

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 50;
params.height = 50;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

or

`button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 100));`